# Python3 - "TypeError: module() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given) "

Tags: python, class, oop, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to create a class that inherits selenium's webdriver but I keep getting: `TypeError: module() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)` when I try to run it

```
class Exploring(webdriver):   #i have also tried class Exploring(selenium.webdriver):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.chrome_options =chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        self.chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
        self.driver.get('https://html-classic.itch.zone/html/7281144/dungeon-crawler-od-v1.1.3-browser/index.html')


    def startup(self):
        input_name = self.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="name-input"]')
        input_name.click()
        time.sleep(1)
        input_name.send_keys("Vacine")
```

when I try running start-up in my `main.py` I get a `TypeError` in my class file:

```
explore = Exploring()
explore.startup()
```

I've done some searching of my own and I think its something to do with webdriver being a module but I'm unsure of how to fix it.

Comment: Please, post full traceback you get

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Workspace\Web Dev Projects\Selenium_dungeon_crawl\main.py", line 4, in <module>     
    from exploring import Exploring
  File "c:\Workspace\Web Dev Projects\Selenium_dungeon_crawl\exploring.py", line 7, in <module>
    class Exploring(selenium.webdriver):
TypeError: module() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)

Comment: and which line is 4 or 7 in the given code?

Comment: line 4: is in my main.py "from exploring import Exploring"
line 7: is in my exploring.py file  "class Exploring(webdriver):"

Comment: @Vacine welcome to SO. Please [edit] additional details into your question rather than posting comments. This is much more readable and makes the question useful for future users. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think below is incorrect:

```
class Exploring(webdriver):
```

You should inherit `Chrome`, so it should be:

```
class Exploring(webdriver.Chrome):
```

Comment: okay this was it thank you for the help!